# How to do something when an AngularUI's modal is closed?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

I'm working with an [AngularUI's modal](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal), and I would like to **change a variable** of my controller when the modal is closed.

My modal looks like this:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="awesomeModal" role="dialog">
    ...
    <button type"button" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
</div>
```

I guess the **close event** of the modal has to do with `data-dismiss`, but I don't find yet how to do something at this specific moment.

---

What I would like to do is to set `$scope.finished = true;` when the modal is closed.

I know I can do something like `<button type"button" data-dismiss="modal" ng-click="finished = false>Close</button>`, but there is, in my opinion, a cleaner way to do it.

Comment: Check docs under `return` https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal Syntax is `$modal.open({/*params here*/}).result.then(function() { /* logic here */ });`

Comment: I saw, but I really don't know how to deal with it. So far I had a very simple use of modal.

 If you think you know how it works, I'm interested you posts a more detailed explanation of it as an answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Since you are asking about $uibModal, here is the event that can be used to capture the modal close event:

```
                var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
                    templateUrl: 'modules/alertTemplates/redirectToModal.html',
                    controller: 'redirectToController',
                    controllerAs: 'redirectToControllerVm',
                    keyboard: false
                    }
                });

                modalInstance.result.then(function () {
                    // called when you close the modal
                    // do your stuff
                }, function () {
                    // called when you dismiss modal by clicking anywhere outside modal
                    // do your stuff
                });
```

Also, if you want you can give the modal template inline using template instead of templateUrl.
Refer following link for better explanation and all the syntax:

```
https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/tree/master/src/modal/docs
```

Comment: Is all this JavaScript needed? Because I don't use a template for the modal, the code is directly in my HTML page. I'm sorry, maybe am I stupid, but it is still unclear for me... :D

Comment: you need to include ui bootstrap.js, then inject $uibModal in your controller. Please refer the link < https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/tree/master/src/modal/docs >. There are demo html and js attached.